# After upgrade to macOS Sierra Apache can't do start/stop/restart

Tags: macos, apache

### After upgrade to macOS Sierra Apache can't do start/stop/restart.

Errors:

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MacBook-Pro-N.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I tried reinstall apache24 using home-brew. But it didn't fix my problem.
Also I configured httpd.conf, uncommented ServerName localhost. But it didn't help anyway.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding 
`127.0.0.1     MacBook-Pro-N.local`

to your `/etc/hosts` file

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change `ServerName` to `localhost`.

So first you need to find the location of your `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file by:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

then edit it and uncomment or change the line with `ServerName` (make sure it has the valid server name or it exists in your `/etc/hosts` file). E.g.

```
ServerName localhost
```